# Swiper ( height issue – multiple swiper – vertical direction )

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe, swiper.js

*I would like to ash here a question, which I asking already in the [developers forum](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/forum/#!/general:height-issue-multiple-swi) of swiper, too. So don't be confused. If a solution is/was found, I will close/mark both.*

At the moment I want for a project a horizontal scrolling sidebar and a vertical scrolling footer. (Swiper based)
But see self what happens if you switch from horizontal (1) footer to a vertical (2) one.

[Video 1 (direction both horizontal - not wanted)](http://www.screencast.com/users/sascha_/folders/Jing/media/cd6751b8-828e-4af4-bc99-7d1c883aa350)

[Video 2 (footer direction vertical, wanted! - not works)](http://www.screencast.com/users/sascha_/folders/Jing/media/0ce9eebd-a521-44fb-930d-6a243ce3271d)

As you can see, on the simplified example (Video 2):
If I use **direction:vertical** on the second swiper-container it breaks the result. Where the HEIGHT of "swiper-slide" should be 226px, appears now a HEIGHT of 2408px and a MARGIN-BOTTOM of 100px.

I really can't understand what's going wrong here.

**ConfInit**

```
var swiper = [];
    $('.swiper-container').each(function(index){

        var $el = $(this);

        var sParams = [{
                speed: 400,
                spaceBetween: 100,
                allowSwipeToNext: false, // for event controlled swipes 
                allowSwipeToPrev: false  // for event controlled swipes 
            },
            {
                speed: 400,
                spaceBetween: 100,
                allowSwipeToNext: false, // for event controlled swipes 
                allowSwipeToPrev: false, // for event controlled swipes 
                direction: 'vertical'
            }
        ];
```

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue, solved by adding `height: 100vh` declaration to swiper container.

### Finding

- `height` property is must

**NOTE:** `%` does not work

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot!